How can I get smooth of this picture?
This is my code.
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1;
h = 2 a;
{pA, pC, pB} = {{0, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0}, {a/2, (Sqrt[3] a)/2 , 0}};
pD = pA + {0, 0, h};
pE = pB + {0, 0, h};
pF = pC + {0, 0, h};
pM = (pB + pC)/2;
p = InfinitePlane[{pD, pB, pC}];
pH = RegionNearest[p, pA]
d = RegionDistance[p, pA]
v = Cross[pD - pB, pD - pC];
Abs[Tan[VectorAngle[v, {0, 0, 1}]]] // Simplify
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ConvexHullRegion[{pA, pB, pC, pD, pE, pF}];
my = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], 
   FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[0.2]}], \[ScriptCapitalR], 
   Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, -0.1}], 
   Text[Style["B", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    pB + {0, 0, -0.1}], 
   Text[Style["C", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    pC + {0, 0, -0.1}], 
   Text[Style["A'", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    pD + {0, 0, 0.1}], 
   Text[Style["B'", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    pE + {0, 0, 0.1}], 
   Text[Style["C'", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    pF + {0, 0, 0.1}], 
   Text[Style["M", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    pM + {0, 0, -0.1}], 
   Text[Style["H", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    pH + {0, 0, -0.1}], Thick, Orange, 
   Line[{{pM, pA}, {pD, pM}, {pD, pB}, {pD, pC}, {pA, pH}}]}, 
  Boxed -> False]



How can I get smooth of this picture?

After the Version 10, Mathematica does not support export 3D graphics with 2D vector format for pdf.

Export as PDF (vector-based, no rasterization):
Export["~/Desktop/my.pdf", my]

Export as high-resolution bitmap:
Export["~/Desktop/my.png", my, ImageResolution -> 2000]

